# I cannot figure out these 3 related errors

Tags: java

I have 3 errors which I cannot fix with my granted, low level of skill.

I am just trying to imput sales figures for year one, which works ok, but I am trying to total the sales below the output and receive errors.

> C:\Users\Steven\Documents\assignment2.java:21: error: '.class'
>   expected
>       System.out.println(int counter + "\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
>
> C:\Users\Steven\Documents\assignment2.java:21: error: not a statement
>           System.out.println(int counter + "\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
>
> C:\Users\Steven\Documents\assignment2.java:21: error: ';' expected
>           System.out.println(int counter + "\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);

The code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment2
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome\n");

        System.out.println("Sales Month\t\tSales made");
        int sales[]={60,54,62,67,54,67,51,50,62,55,49,70};
        int sum=0;

        for(int counter=0;counter < sales.length;counter++)
        {
            sum+=sales [counter];

        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the sales is " +sum);
        System.out.println(int counter + "\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);

    }
```

}

Comment: What do you expect the last println to do?

Comment: @rghome I thought it would output the month number vertically and the sales made output to its right, like a table format.

Comment: It needs to be in a loop then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  public class assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome\n");
        System.out.println("Sales Month\t\tSales made");
        int sales[] = { 60, 54, 62, 67, 54, 67, 51, 50, 62, 55, 49, 70 };
        int sum = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < sales.length; counter++) {
            sum += sales[counter];
            System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the sales is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has made the program run @Arpit. What was I doing wrong on the println where the errors occured?

Comment: You are trying to access `counter` variable outside the scope. If you want to access `counter` variable declare it outside the loop.

Comment: Like : `int counter;
  for (counter = 0; counter < sales.length; counter++) {
   sum += sales[counter];
   System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
  }
  System.out.println(counter + " The sum of the sales is " + sum);`

Comment: Ok thank you, with your edit the table outputs nicely, although I have 'sales month' not telling me what month the sales figure is for when I run the programme. What should I add to make this happen?

Comment: Edited the answer, run it and let me know if it is what you need:)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `int` from in front of `counter` in `int counter + "\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]`

Also, counter was declared in your for loop, but you're using it outside of it. Declare it before your for loop or put that line inside your for loop.

I just compiled and ran with my changes, it works. Here is the output:

```
    Sales Month             Sales made                                                                                                                                                                                        
0                               60                                                                                                                                                                                        
1                               54                                                                                                                                                                                        
2                               62                                                                                                                                                                                        
3                               67                                                                                                                                                                                        
4                               54                                                                                                                                                                                        
5                               67                                                                                                                                                                                        
6                               51                                                                                                                                                                                        
7                               50                                                                                                                                                                                        
8                               62                                                                                                                                                                                        
9                               55                                                                                                                                                                                        
10                              49                                                                                                                                                                                        
11                              70                                                                                                                                                                                        
The sum of the sales is 701
```

Comment: Won't compile either.

Comment: @AlexK. No, it isn't.

Comment: Or keep it in the loop and just print `sales.length`

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here..

```
    class assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome\n");

        System.out.println("Sales Month\t\tSales made");
        int sales[] = { 60, 54, 62, 67, 54, 67, 51, 50, 62, 55, 49, 70 };
        int sum = 0;
        int counter;
        for (counter = 0; counter < sales.length; counter++) {
            sum += sales[counter];
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the sales is " + sum);

    }
}
```

you can not declare any **variable** in **println** statement just remove it and declare it before for loop (**make it instance variable**)

Comment: Won't compile either as `counter` is no longer in scope at that point.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as [@Olivier Poulin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4974174/olivier-poulin) stated, remove the `int` keyword.

Also, the `counter` variable is not is the scope. It is defined in the for loop and **does not exist** outside of it.

To avoid that just declare it outside of the `for` loop.

Finally, the counter is just equivalent to `sales.length` as you always increment by 1. Therefore, your code should look like this :

```
int counter;
for (; counter < sales.length; counter++) {  // initialization is done outside the for loop
            sum += sales[counter];
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
        }

System.out.println(sales.length + "\t\t\t\t" + sales[sales.length - 1]);
```

Have a look at the java tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 0):

From this line

```
System.out.println(int counter + "\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
```

Remove int

Data type is given only while declaring variables you cannot declare it there.Infact you"ll have to remove the whole line as counter is declared inside loop and this statement is out side loop.after removing int put in inside the for loop body

Comment: Won't compile either as `counter` is no longer in scope at that point.

Comment: You'll have to remove that line counter is declared inside loop and you're trying to use it outside loop block you'll get error.check my answer i have edit it